# How can I remove Godot's splash screen?

Tags: godot

I started using Godot lately (mostly because the editor supports Linux).

There is one thing that bothers me: the Godot splash screen. I know that I can (somehow) remove it and I saw something about C but I'm not sure.

Is there any way to remove it? Or maybe it is only in the editor and once you export the game it'll disappear?

Comment: Do you mean the starting splash screen? There are several mentions to removing or replacing it through a quick Google search, including [The GODOT forums](http://godotdevelopers.org/index.php?topic=7194.0) and [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/godot/comments/3ek1wj/how_do_i_remove_the_godot_icon_in_my_export/).

Comment: I mean the scree that shows for 5 frames ( until loading is done)

Comment: Why would you want to remove the splash? Be proud of it. Support the engine. That way when your game gets more popular then other people can see the engine and contribute to it. If you really want to replace it, then examine the C++ code till you find it and replace it with something... I personally prefer that rather than a black frozen screen while the engine loads.

Comment: @rlam12 I agree, one should not be ashamed to be using the Godot Engine, but still, especially for a piece of software that wants to be free as in freedom, it's incredibly important that it *can* be disabled. You should, enable it, because you're also allowed to disable it, if you know what i mean. That's (apart from all the technical advantages) what makes Godot special!

Comment: I think they changed it now so you have to have a bootsplash so what I do is put there is a white screen that says loading...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Go to Scene > Project Settings > Application and change the `boot_splash` property.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Go to "Project" menu, select "Project settings…" which opens the "Project Settings" dialog. On the left panel select "Application" and inside "Boot Splash". On the right you will find the setting "Image", you can select the image you want to appear there.

Leaving it blank will result in the default image.

[image: Project Settings dialog with Boot Splash selected]

And yes, you can place a path that does not exist, and it will fail loading the image (instead you get a white screen), and the game still shows up. However, I suggest to place your own image instead.

I'll also suggest to use an image with transparency, and have black background. Why black? Well, if you export for Android and rotate the screen while the splash screen is up, it will show black bars while rotating. If the background is also black, the user won't notice.

---

As you know, the splash screen will stay up as long as it takes to load the start scene. This means that a start scene that loads faster translates to less splash screen time.

You may take this to your advantage: create a small scene that shows a picture that matches the splash screen (so the user does not notice the change), and loads your main scene in the background (see [Background loading](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/io/background_loading.html)). That way you can have a progress bar, have animation, and fade out to reveal your main scene.

Answer (score 0):

Project settings > application.
Enter in `boot_splash`: `null.png`.
The engine will not find the image "null" and will leave an empty background.